# Relacionamento entre tabelas variando de acordo com valor

Tags: sql

Tenho uma tabela que pode gravar o `id` de refêrencia(FK) em mais de uma coluna.

Preciso fazer um select que faça o vínculo com a primeira coluna de referência e caso ela seja nula, realizar o vinculo através da segunda coluna.

Minha query:

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM nfs n
  , nfs_item ni
  , pedido_entrega pe 
WHERE n.id = ni.nfs_id 
  AND ni.pedido_entrega_id = pe.id
```

Veja que a `nfs_item` se relaciona com a `pedido_entrega` através do `pedido_entrega_id`. Porém, por vezes essa coluna estará com valor `null` e a referência ficará gravada em uma coluna chamada `pedido_entrega_id_origem`.

Portanto, hora vou relacionar essas tabelas através do `ni.pedido_entrega_id = pe.id` e hora vou relacionar elas através do `ni.pedido_entrega_id_origem = pe.id`. Como faço isso?

Comment: Existe algum caso em que a tabela1 possui as duas colunas preenchidas (id_tabela1 e id_origem ) ?

Comment: Não, ela ou vai ter a info em uma ou em outra, nunca nas duas juntas.

Comment: Beleza, vou adequar aqui e te aviso, obrigado desde já.

Comment: Olá, bom dia, não deu certo. Vou colocar a query aqui, acredito que ajuda no entendimento:

select * from nfs n, nfs_item ni, pedido_entrega pe
     where n.id = ni.nfs_id
     and ni.pedido_entrega_id = pe.id

Veja que a nfs_item se relaciona com a pedido_entrega através do pedido_entrega_id. Porém, por vezes essa coluna está em branco e esse id fica gravado em uma coluna chamada pedido_entrega_id_origem. Portanto, hora vou relacionar essas tabelas através do "ni.pedido_entrega_id = pe.id" e hora vou relacionar elas através do "ni.pedido_entrega_id_origem = pe.id". Como faço isso?

Comment: Alterei minha resposta, também fiz uma simulação online e funcionou. Veja se te atende.

Comment: Coloque o banco de dados q vc ta usando e se possível mostre-nos as tabelas ou pelo menos os campos delas....

Comment: Uso banco de dados Oracle, mas consegui resolver, vou complementar com uma resposta. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizei o `JOIN` e na cláusula `ON` eu verifico para ambas as colunas se a referência existe ou se e valor é nulo:

[SQLFiddle - Exemplo Online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f9abd/2)

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  nfs n
JOIN nfs_item ni
  ON n.id = ni.nfs_id
JOIN pedido_entrega pe
  ON (
    ni.pedido_entrega_id = pe.id
    OR ni.pedido_entrega_id IS NULL
  )
  AND (
    ni.pedido_entrega_id_origem = pe.id
    OR ni.pedido_entrega_id_origem IS NULL
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a famosa logica do OR (muito conhecida no if).

O 'OR' eu costumo usar muito no postgresql, então não garanto que vai funcionar no seu caso. para eu e a comunidade te ajudar melhor, edite sua pergunta e coloque uma foto das tabelas e também me diga o banco de dados que vc está utilizando...
Como não sei se vc esta usando pgsql, mysql, mssql eu vou só colocar a parte do JOIN mesmo. segue o código:

```
SELECT .... FROM nfs_item ni 
INNER JOIN nome_tabela pe ON ((ni.pedido_entrega_id = pe.id) OR (ni.pedido_entrega_id_origem = pe.id))
```

Claro que como eu não sei qual banco vc ta usando, eu n pude testar o código, mas a lógica para o que vc quer fazer é essa. (talvez se tiver alguma regra de negocio a mais é so vc mudar pra LEFT JOIN ou caso queira que não mostre valores nulos é só vc colocar um where e tal)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver com o seguinte galera.
Fiz um select após o from somente para vincular com minhas tabelas:

SELECT
  * 
FROM nfs n
  , (select pedido_entrega_id||pedido_entrega_id_origem entrega_id, id item_nfs_id from nfs_item) nfs_item_vinculo
  , nfs_item ni
  , pedido_entrega pe 
WHERE and n.id = ni.nfs_id 
and nfs_item_vinculo.item_nfs_id = ni.id
and nfs_item_vinculo.entrega_id = pe.id

Obrigado pessoal.